# How to Authorize request from another WebApi project

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, asp.net-identity

There are 2 WebApi Projects on different servers. One of these servers (WebApi-A) has `OAuth2` authentication workflow setup with Authorization Server and all.

The another WebApi project (WebApi-B) has an end point that I would like to Authenticate through `[Authorize]` attribute. I don't want have a new authorization server but to utilize (WebApi-A's) authentication process just to validate the token.

From what I understand if the machine-key is same across these server. We can essentially replicate the authentication process from `WebApi-A` in `WebApi-B` without having to call `WebApi-A` at all.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Clarification, do you have a frontend ? And are you looking for a SSO behavior ? Or else is this all happening in the backend

Comment: Doesn't really matter if I have a frontend or not. The call can happen through an external webapi too.

Comment: Need clarification of Web Api B. This still has no Authorization set up?

Answer (score 0):

You could, in theory, pass through the JWT token and if your OAuth setup uses the same client secret and data store it should just work.  You would have to ensure that you add the JTW token when requesting and to use some distributed cache to verify.

I would rather ask whether or not you should rather create a gateway that can handle and authenticate the requests and delegate them to the separate APIs?  This feels like an identity server (http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/apis.html) would solve your problem.  Anything you do other than moving the authentication from web api A would just be a stopgap.

Duplicating the setup could work but that will mean that you have to now maintain it in two places. So I agree that doing that is less than ideal.

This is a great article that may aid you:

https://www.scottbrady91.com/OAuth/Delegation-Patterns-for-OAuth-20

Comment: I tried executing this but wasn't able to make it work. Frankly its too much abstraction with Asp.Net Identity that its impossible to get it done without some domain knowledge. IdentityServer seems like a 3rd party paid service.

Comment: It is a free service you can add it as a nuget package.  https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/overview/simplestOAuth.html

Answer (score 0):

This will have a lengthy answer so I will just leave you this diagram showing multiple Resource Server, Client, and a separate Authorization Server

[image]

Taken from this article [Single sign-on across multiple applications (part II)](https://medium.com/@adrianmihaila/single-sign-on-across-multiple-applications-part-ii-a8a48e4a7c11) which I hope could get you started.

Answer (score -1):

you can use your token when login in web api and then you add the token to the header "Authorization" with bearer "your token"